# netty ioworker write task queue may grow unlimited

Tags: netty

regarding IOworker's writeTaskQueue. it seems it should contain at the maximum, number of channels the worker is in charge of. yet, I keep reproducing a scenario where the queue gets filled a lot more than that. I saw a jira on jboss community about it that was eventually resolved as non bug. does it mean the write task queue can be filled a lot more than the number of channels its in charge of? and if so, is there still a logical bound to this queue size?

Answer (score 0):

You should check with Channel.isWritable() if there is enough memory left for the Channel to queue bytes. The limit can be set via the writeBufferHighWaterMark and writeBufferLowWaterMark

See:
http://static.netty.io/3.5/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/socket/nio/NioChannelConfig.html